# Yum module not found ansible

Tags: vagrant, ansible, vagrant-provision

I'm very new to Vagrant and Ansible, somehow I managed to setup Vagrant and have a box running but when i try to provision it with Ansible then I get error.`ImportError: No module named yum`

My playbook looks like below :-

```
---
- hosts: default
  connection: local
  sudo: true
  tasks:

  - name: install apache
    yum: name=httpd state=latest
```

I'm using Ubuntu as my host machine and have Vagrant 1.8.5 and latest version of Ansible on it.Can somebody please suggest where I'm mistaking. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, `sudo: true` is deprecated. Use `become: true` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With

```
connection: local
```

you are running the playbook on your host which is Ubuntu.

And that's why it doesn't find yum.

Comment: my host machine is running Ubuntu and my virtual machine (spawned by Vagrant ) is running centos/7 so I guess I need yum to install apache on centos and not apt

Comment: Ahh... that was the problem, thanks a lot for pointing the problem, I got it running :)